# No. of distinct matrices satisfying a certain equation

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> **[TIFR-GS 2011, Part B, problem no. 1]** Let $A$ be a $2×2$ matrix with complex entries. The no. of $2×2$ matrices A with complex entries satisfying the equation $A^3=A$ is infinite. They asked if the statement is true or false.

From the given equation, I've found that the eigenvalues of $A$ can be $0$, $1$, and $-1$. Now I took a trial matrix and tried to satisfy the equation, but it doesn't help in any way. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The identity doesn't have trace $1$ or determinant $0$.

Comment: Okay, identity matrix just have the eigenvalue $1$. Thanks for correcting my route.

Comment: Plus, there is the possible eigenvalue $-1$.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I computer it wrong. $0$, $1$, $-1$ are the roots of characteristic equation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any basis $\{x_1,x_2\}$ of $\mathbb{C}^2$, any linear transformation $A:\mathbb{C}^2\to\mathbb{C}^2$ with eigenvectors $x_1$ and $x_2$ and eigenvalues $-1, 0,$ or $1$ satisfies the equation.

Comment: (+1) Nice point of view.

Comment: Got it !! Since any matrix is some sort of linear transformation, it'll happen for all L.T having eigenvalues $0$, $1$, $-1$ !!

Answer (score 2):

Since $X^3-X$ has only roots with multiplicity $1$, such a matrix $A$ has to be diagonalizable. So you are looking at the set $$\left\{A=P\left(\matrix{a&0\\0&b}\right)P^{-1}\mid P\text{ is invertible and }a,b\in\{-1,0,1\}\right\}$$
The three subsets corresponding to $a=b$ have one element each, now what happens when $a\neq b$?

For instance, $$\left\{\left(\matrix{1&0\\z&1}\right)\left(\matrix{1&0\\0&-1}\right)\left(\matrix{1&0\\-z&1}\right)\mid z\in\Bbb C\right\}$$
is infinite.